# 1.9.3 - Catalog > Manage Products > Show Price including tax (backend)

Tags: product, admin, backend, tax, magento1.9.3

In the catalog manager and products manager the prices all show as excluding tax.

This behaviour is correct but in Australia we mostly read prices as a whole (inc tax) and break the tax out in invoices.

The front end is displaying correctly as it shows the inc tax for the price but in the admin (backend) the price shows as the ex price.
I was wanting to know if you can add another line that shows the inc price below the ex. price or comment out ex price and just show inc price.

magento 1.9.3 CE

Also have Products Manager (Advanced) installed but it follows the same behaviour.

I am not sure if this needs to be coded or if there is a configuration setting.  I have tried looking for the answer but most are concerned with the front end.

Any help would be grand.

Cheers